# LUKS encrypted root timer

Tags: pi-zero-w

Is there any possibility to add a timer to initramfs? I have encrypted root on Raspberry Pi Zero W and it can be unlocked only by SSH. Sometimes i turn on RPi by accident (too much to explain) and I don't want to corrupt SD Card so I need to turn on my computer, connect to RPi, unlock and do "poweroff". But if i could add a simple timer that turns off RPi after 180 seconds that would solve my problem.